# Axios and React spams API when Express API returns a random number everytime

Tags: reactjs, api, express, axios

I'm trying to build a react component that is showing a random number based of an API response. But I notice that the number displayed is infinitely re-rendered and it when I check the server console, it receives infinite request from react. How to solve this? I am using react state to display the number.

API randomnumber.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    res.send({
        "number": randomNumber
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

React Component

```
import react, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'

interface Props {

}

export default function RandomNumber(props: Props) {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/api/random-number",

    }).then(
        ((result) => {
            setNumber(result.data.number)
        })
    )

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{number}</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

I want the server to return 1 random number per request, and react will render that number.

Comment: you should the side-effects like fetching an API in an [useEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#useeffect) ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the [side-effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure#side-effects-unintended-consequences) in [useEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#useeffect) Hook or you can use libraries like TANstack query etc., but it depends and a simple one like so should do the job ...

```
export default function RandomNumber(props: Props) {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/api/random-number",
    }).then((result) => {
      setNumber(result.data.number);
    });
  }, []);   // `[]` means run the effect once on mount

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

- In your code, what is really happening is, on every render, the `axios` call happens and it sets a new state which causes a re-render again and the same cycle repeats which cause infinite requests

Answer (score 0):

You can't update state as you do in your sample, because every `setState` call will trigger re-rendering and will re-evaluate your code again ending up in infinite loop. Instead you should be calling your fetching logic "onComponentMount" with useEffect hook and empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "/api/random-number",

    }).then(
        ((result) => {
            setNumber(result.data.number)
    })
)
}, [])
```